# CentOS - Prevent forwarded connections from NIC #2 through default gateway on NIC #1

Tags: linux, networking, centos, routing, network-adapter

I have a CentOS 7 system with 2 NICs (eth0 and eth1).

NIC configurations:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
      inet 10.43.96.210  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 10.43.96.255

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
      inet 146.81.34.150  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 146.81.34.255
```

My current routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway        Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0        10.43.96.193   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.43.96.192   0.0.0.0        255.255.255.192 U     100    0        0 eth0
146.81.34.0    0.0.0.0        255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eth1
146.81.34.128  146.81.34.254  255.255.255.128 UG    0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0        255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
```

NIC eth0 is connected to 10.43.96.x network and the default gateway (10.43.96.193) is used for outgoing connections to public Internet from computers within the 10.43.96.x network.

NIC eth1 is connected to 146.81.34.128/25 network (NIC IP 146.81.34.150, netmask 255.255.255.128, gw 146.81.34.254, these are defined by the customer) and needs to access a server at IP 146.81.34.11.

Other servers from 146.81.0.0/16 network need to reach my server (146.81.34.150) with ping (through gateway 146.81.34.254). For example, server at 146.81.23.95 needs to ping my server. I don't know more about the network and routing configuration details in that network, I was told to use their gateway 146.81.34.254.

**Current problem:**

The customer says that other servers from 146.81.0.0/16 network (146.81.x.x) can reach the 146.81.34.128/25 network correctly (and thus can reach my server at 146.81.34.150 with ping). This is fine.

However, the other servers in 146.81.0.0/16 network now try to reach other IP addresses (in other networks than 146.81.34.128/25) through my server by using my default gateway (10.43.96.193), which should be prevented.

**Question:**

How should I prevent forwarded connections through this server from servers in 146.81.0.0/16 network? They should not be using the default gateway (10.43.96.193) on my server.

Comment: Does "146.81.34.x" here mean "146.81.34.0/24" or "146.81.34.0/25"?

Comment: "the other servers […] now try to reach other IP addresses (in other networks than 146.81.34.128/25) through my default gateway" vs "How should I prevent incoming connections from servers" – you seem to be talking about two entirely different things here; are you really asking about incoming connections _to this server_ or about forwarded connections _through this server_?

Comment: Thanks for the comments and sorry for my badly formatted question. I edited my question to be hopefully more clear. I am asking about preventing forwarded connections through my server. My server is connected to 146.81.34.128/25 network, and they need to ping my server 146.81.34.150 from 146.81.0.0/16 network through gateway 146.81.34.254 (for example, server 146.81.23.95 pings my server).

Comment: I'm curious why those connections to "other IP addresses" would happen to begin with. Are the servers using you as their default gateway? Is this _already_ happening, or are you just trying to prevent it from being done maliciously?

Comment: Yes, this is already happening. It seems they are using me as a default gateway, which is quite astonishing. I am waiting for their answer to that. Fortunately this is a testing network, not a production network.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I prevent forwarded connections through this server from servers in 146.81.0.0/16 network?

The simplest option would be to *completely* disable IP forwarding, via sysctl:

- `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=0`
- `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0`

If *some* kinds of traffic must be forwarded through the server, but others not, use the firewall – just add rules accepting the wanted traffic, and rejecting (or dropping) the rest.

- iptables has the `FORWARD` chain for precisely this purpose.
- nft likewise has the `forward` hook.